# I cannot get string from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a [self.post post_time] NSDate with value of 2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSLog([formatter stringFromDate:[self.post post_time]]);
```

It doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like self.post post_time is returning nil.

Comment: No; it returns 2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first**, the timezone does make you headache, because the `NSDateFormatter` can recognise the following formats for the timezones i.e. `+0000` or `GMT+1000` but it cannot recognise the timezones with colon, `+00:00`, simply, there is no pattern for it. so, somehow you should remove the colon from the timezone part.

**second**, you have to use the following pattern for your input date instead of the `yyyy-mm-dd` because this patter does not cover your input string.

```
NSString *_dateString = @"2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00";
NSString *_noColonInTimezone = [_dateString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(_dateString.length-3, 1) withString:@""];
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZZZ"];
NSDate *_date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_noColonInTimezone];
NSLog(@"raw date : %@", _date);
```

it is working well, **it has been tested on real device**, I'm hoping it helps you to get the `NSDate` object with correct date and then you can format the date for the output as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

your code works for me

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSz"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00"]; // simulate your attribute

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

Comment: It works for [NSDate date] but not for my value. 2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00

Comment: No, NSDate value. I am reading it from a JSON with post_time = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"post_time"];

Comment: are you sure your not nil NSDate?

Comment: @Burak That is because your format is set incorrect. Set the format of the NSDateFormatter to match your date format and you're safe. 2012-08-02T08:57:52.152713+00:00 does not match "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: but in this way post_time is a string - post_time = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"post_time"];

Comment: NSLog([self.post post_time]); gives the date value. How can I read a json to NSDate other than that way?